# android - how to open a local file in android

Tags: android, file, kml

I am trying to open a local kml file which is in my sdcard but i am getting error.In stackoverflow itself i have seen some questions related to this but they are not answered and some are not related to this.

[android - how to open kml file in android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15811558/android-how-to-open-kml-file-in-android)

[Android - How to open google maps with Intent and KML?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7965747/android-how-to-open-google-maps-with-intent-and-kml)

My code

```
public void openKMLFile(View v)

    final Intent myIntent = new Intent(android.content.Intent.ACTION_VIEW, 
            Uri.parse("geo:0,0?q=file://" + Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory() + "/test.kml"));
    startActivity(myIntent);
}
```

Android Manifest file  i have given this permission

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.example.demo"
    android:versionCode="1"
    android:versionName="1.0" >

    <uses-sdk
        android:minSdkVersion="8"
        android:targetSdkVersion="16" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET"/>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"/>

    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >

        <activity
            android:name="com.example.demo.MainActivity"
            android:label="@string/app_name" >
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
    </application>

</manifest>
```

Logcat Error :

```
04-05 11:42:01.806: E/AndroidRuntime(833): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
04-05 11:42:01.806: E/AndroidRuntime(833): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.example.demo/com.example.demo.MainActivity}: android.content.ActivityNotFoundException: No Activity found to handle Intent { act=android.intent.action.VIEW dat=geo:0,0?q=file:///mnt/sdcard/10.kml }
04-05 11:42:01.806: E/AndroidRuntime(833): Caused by: android.content.ActivityNotFoundException: No Activity found to handle Intent { act=android.intent.action.VIEW dat=geo:0,0?q=file:///mnt/sdcard/10.kml }
```

Your help is greatly appreciated.Thank You

Comment: the exception which is throw means that you don't have any other program which can handler / open kml file as I understand.

Comment: put this in your intent filter in manifest maybe <action android:name="android.intent.action.navigon.START_PUBLIC" />

Comment: Have a look into this http://stackoverflow.com/a/7107427/1329126

Comment: I ran this in emulator..so what can i do for this? do i need to change any settings in android

Comment: @sankar i need to open this file when there is no internet.so only i kept this file local and try to open that not from url

Comment: make sure before sending the intent whether there is an activity to handle your intent using the PackageManager packageManager = getPackageManager();

Comment: @Jrowan :that does not work friend

Comment: ok sorry i got parse google.navigation: not with file with lat and lng though i was just wondring